# A three-column align environment is problematic

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, align

Consider the following badly typeset system of equations:

[image]

What I want to produce instead (I used a picture editing software to create this) is

[image]

Ok, the spacing between the `\Longleftrightarrow` and the `=` is a bit tight, but I assume this can be easily fixed by introducing `\,` (unless there's a more elegant way, where the spacing is handled by the environment).
 How can I do that ?

---

The code for the top, baldy typeset system is

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 & x+y & =xy+y^{2}x^{2}+3x+7\\
\Longleftrightarrow & x+y & =3u+4v\\
\Longleftrightarrow & xy & =3u+4v
\end{alignat*}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply forgot that for `2` alignment points, you need `3&`, and more  generally, k alignment points require 2k – 1 ampersands: each group except the first uses one `&` to introduce the new group and one `&` to set the alignment point within this group. As to the spacing after  `\iff`, it can be set adding a pair of braces. So the code should be:
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \begin{document}

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 & & x+y & =xy+y^{2}x^{2}+3x+7\\
& \Longleftrightarrow{} & x+y & =3u+4v\\
 & \Longleftrightarrow{} & xy & =3u+4v
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]